# Swift 2 to 3 Migration for AnyObject JSON Error

Tags: json, swift, swift2, swift3, ios10

I'm attempting to convert the following code from this library (https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json) into Swift 3 Compatible code.

Only a few errors left to solve.  I'm stuck on this line now.

```
extension JSON : Sequence {
```

The error I get is **'Type 'JSON' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'**

Its full context is below.  I looked in the source code to see if Sequence already existed as a protocol to see how to conform but not sure where it comes from.  I know this worked in Swift 2.

```
extension JSON : Sequence {
    public func generate()->AnyIterator<(AnyObject,JSON)> {
        switch _value {
        case let o as NSArray:
            var i = -1
            return AnyIterator {
                i=i+1
                if i == o.count { return nil }
                return (i, JSON(o[i]))
            }
        case let o as NSDictionary:
            var ks = Array(o.allKeys.reversed())
            return AnyIterator {
                if ks.isEmpty { return nil }
                if let k = ks.removeLast() as? String {
                    return (k, JSON(o.value(forKey: k)!))
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        default:
            return AnyIterator{ nil }
        }
    }
    public func mutableCopyOfTheObject() -> AnyObject {
        return _value.mutableCopy as AnyObject
    }
}
```

Both the return statements also give an error if that is connected somehow.

```
return (i, JSON(o[i]))
```

and...

```
return (k, JSON(o.value(forKey: k)!))
```

Both give the same error, **'Cannot convert return expression of type '(String,JSON)' to return type '(AnyObject, JSON)?'**

I assume to fix that I have to cast the value i and k in the return statements to AnyObject? I'm not sure though.

Here is a detailed screenshot of the suggestions it gives me.  Not sure how to change the code though yet.

[image]

Comment: Try to replace `AnyObject` with `Any`

Answer (score 1):

return (i, JSON(o[i])) ===>  return (i as AnyObject, JSON(o[i]))

The data types in swift3 are more stringent than swift2.

Comment: Will this fix the sequence part also? I will try now.

Comment: sequence error still saying not conforming to sequence any ideas?

Comment: You did help fix the return errors though, thanks for that!